# GridView item not changing when value is changed

Tags: java, android, gridview, arraylist

i have this class

```
public class Item {
    String image;
    String accesslevel;
    String username;
    String userjob;
    String usercompany;
    String usermail;
    Boolean etat;
    int userapartid;
    public Item(String image, String username, String userjob, String usercompany, String usermail,int userapartid,Boolean etat,String accesslevel) {
        super();
        this.userapartid=userapartid;
        this.image = image;
        this.username = username;
        this.userjob = userjob;
        this.usercompany = usercompany;
        this.usermail = usermail;
        this.etat=etat;
        this.accesslevel=accesslevel;
    }
    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }
    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
    public String getusername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setusername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getusercompany() {
        return usercompany;
    }
    public void setusercompany(String usercompany) {
        this.usercompany = usercompany;
    }
    public String getuserjob() {
        return userjob;
    }
    public void setuserjob(String userjob) {
        this.userjob = userjob;
    }
    public String getusermail() {
        return usermail;
    }
    public void setusermail(String usermail) {
        this.usermail = usermail;
    }
    public Boolean getetat() {
        return etat;
    }
    public void setetat(Boolean etat) {
        this.etat = etat;
    }

    public int getuserapartid() {
        return userapartid;
    }
    public void setuserapartid(int userapartid) {
        this.userapartid = userapartid;
    }


    public String getaccesslevel() {
        return accesslevel;
    }
    public void setaccesslevel(String accesslevel) {
        this.accesslevel = accesslevel;
    }

}
```

And i have a GridView filled by Item in my main application and an arraylist that contains the item

```
gridArray2 = new ArrayList<Item>();

for(int i=0;i<gridArray.size();i++){                                             
     __Item = new Item(gridArray.get(i).getImage(),gridArray.get(i).getusername(),gridArray.get(i).getuserjob(),gridArray.get(i).getusercompany(),gridArray.get(i).getusermail(),gridArray.get(i).getuserapartid(),gridArray.get(i).getetat(),gridArray.get(i).getaccesslevel());



gridArray2.add(__Item);

       }
 customGridAdapter = new CustomGridViewAdapter(MainActualite.this, R.layout.row_grid_access, gridArray2);
gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);
```

My problem is when i do this:

```
gridView2.get(2).setetat(true);
```

the value of etat in the item is not changed. What can I do to change the value of an item in an arraylist please??

Thanks!

Comment: Did you call `customGridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after that?

Comment: what is the `gridView2` variable? Show us where and how you are changing this

Comment: Are you sure you tried `gridView2.get(2).setetat(true);` and not `gridArray2.get(2).setetat(true)`?

Comment: As per the current code posted your `gridArray2` is an empty list. does this statement `gridView2.get(2).setetat(true); ` produce any exceptions ?

Answer (score 0):

When you change the data that is being provided to an adapter (in this case you are updating `GridArray2` which is providing `customGridAdapter` with data), you always need to make sure to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to let the adapter for your `GridView` know that the underlying dataset has changed.

More information on this function can be found here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 0):

Basically, to update data in gridview, you have to update the data object (can be array, list, or something. But usually a list). After you change the content (lets say, a list), you have to call `customGridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`.

And anyway, you do not need to re-instantiate your adapter.